# Can't pass php value in a form's value

Tags: php, html

I am trying to pre-fill my form with data that is found in my .php file. Please, what am I doing wrong? The form field displays exactly what is found in between quotes.

```
<form  id='registration' method="POST" action="m.php" >
 Username:<br><input type="read-only" name="username" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($ss); ?>" /><br>
```

This is the .php file

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION["logged_in"] == true){
    $ss=$_SESSION['username'];
    }
else $ss="nu";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The file containing the form html code should also be named and executed as php (and have the .php extension alongside the other one). Otherwise php doesn't get executed inside the html code and you end up with php code sent as-is to the browser.

Comment: You mean I should change the extension of my html file to php?

Comment: absolutely, since it contains at least one php statement inside and you want it executed server-side.

Comment: Yes. Other simple solution is to declare PHP Handler for html files. If you use .htaccess, add this line AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm to the root .htaccess file. There are other way you can implement this, like using rewrites or front controller, but simpy renaming your file to .php extension or adding a php handler to html files will be fine for your case.

Answer (score 0):

The action attribute is used to inform the browser what page (or script) to call once the "submit" button is pressed, this is why you are not loading the username

You need to add that php script into the page the form is on as opposed to adding it to the forms processing functionality.

Here is a read on the action attribute
https://www.sitepoint.com/action-html-attribute/

let me know if I can be of further assistance but that change should get you up and running.